# Fork and Pipe program not working properly

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, child-process

I'm trying to code a simple fork() and pipe() program which gets input from the user and outputs it through the pipe in the childprocess. But somehow I'm not getting the result I wished to get.

The first input works fine, for example I type in "Hi" and get the result "Prozessmanager: Hi", but as soon as I try to input the next string, it crashes or somehow stops working until I input a "Q" which exits my Program.

I tried to debug it and got the result, that I'm trying to write into a broken pipe.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    //#include <signal.h>

    #define BUFSIZE 512
    //int clock = 0;

    //void handler(int signum) {
    //clock++;
    //printf("Clock: 00:00:%d\n", clock);
    //}

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        pid_t prozessmanager;
        pid_t reporter;
        int pipefd[2];
        int status;
        char str[BUFSIZE];
        char buf[BUFSIZE];


        if ((pipe(pipefd)) == -1) {
            perror("pipe() error");
            exit(1);
        }

        if ((prozessmanager = fork()) == -1) {
            perror("fork() error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (prozessmanager == 0) { //Prozessmanager prozess
            while (1) {
                //signal(SIGALRM, handler);
                //while(1){
                //alarm(1);
                //}
                close(pipefd[1]);
                read(pipefd[0], buf, sizeof (buf));
                /*if (*buf == 'S') {
                    //handler(clock);
                } else {*/
                if (*buf == 'P') {
                    if ((reporter = fork()) == -1) {
                        perror("fork() error");
                        exit(1);
                    } else if (reporter == 0) { //Reporter prozess
                        printf("Im a Report Prozess, PID: %d\n", getpid());
                        exit(0);
                    } else { //Prozessmanager waits for Reporter
                        wait(&status);
                        printf("Report terminated, PID: %d\n", reporter);
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (*buf == 'Q') {
                    printf("Exit Prozessmanager, PID: %d\n", getpid());
                    exit(0);
                } else {
                    printf("Prozessmanager: %s", buf);
                    break;
                }
                //}
            }
        } else { //Kommandant prozess
            while (1) {
                close(pipefd[0]);
                fgets(str, 80, stdin);
                write(pipefd[1], str, sizeof (str));
                if (*str == 'Q') {
                    break;
                }
            }
            wait(&status);
            printf("Exit Kommandant, PID: %d\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
        return (0);
    }
```

Comment: You don't know how many bytes were read because you discard the return value from `read()`.  That's always a bad idea; you must check what you get from input functions.  You need to know how many bytes were sent to you, too.  You also need to be able to detect when the pipe is closed; the return value from `read()` tells you that, too.  Similarly with the writing.  You're sending the whole buffer even if you only got three bytes input.  Note that if you write `Quite extraordinary` as input, your input loop will terminate.

Comment: Thx for your reply, how exactly do I check for the return value of read. I read the man page of it and tried something like if(read == -1) -> error. but somehow it skips it because read is not -1

Comment: `int nbytes = read(…); if (nbytes == -1) {…error…} else if (nbytes == 0) {…EOF…} else {…process one or more bytes…}`.